# Ansible playbook with multiple roles and Gitlab pipeline

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run multiple roles using Ansible in a Gitlab pipeline, but for some reason it runs only the first role in the list and finishes the pipeline as successfull. Example playbook.yml below:

```
 - name: My play
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  roles:
    - location/approle1
    - location/approle2
    - location/approle3
```

In this case only the role ***approle1*** is executed, then the pipeline finishes, no errors or messages. If the ***approle1*** line is removed or commented and the Gitlab pipeline stage run again, ***approle2*** is executed, but not ***approle3***. Any ideia of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add role: before the role's path.

```
- name: My play
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: location/approle1
    - role: location/approle2
    - role: location/approle3
```

Comment: Thank for your answer @wassim, but the behavior remains the same after making the changes as suggested, at least for me.